# How to get checked checkbox and associated text box value in an array and append this value to url using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my scenario there is a list of items, check box and quantity field text box is assigned to each item. What i want to achieve is to get all checked check box and associated quantity field text box value in an array and append it to url.

Need to pass these values in below mentioned url

shopping.sandbox.netsuite.com/app/site/backend/additemtocart.nl?c=4030365&n=1&buyid=multi&multi=checkboxvalue,quantityvalue;checkboxvalue,quantityvalue; etc

This is my html code

> ```
> <a href="" onclick="javascript:addURL(this);alert(this.href);" id="ct1">Add to cart</a> 
> <div class="cell-checkbox">
> <input type="checkbox" name="select" value="    
> <%=getCurrentAttribute('item','internalid')%>" class="big">
> </div>
> <div class="cell-cart">
> <input name="qty" id="qty" value="1" class="input">
> </div>
> ```

using <%=getCurrentAttribute('item','internalid')%> i'm getting checkbox value.
on clicking add to cart anchor tag below mentioned script is executing.

What i have tried so far

```
<script>
function addURL(element)
{     
var qtyvalue = document.getElementById("qty").value;
var val = [];  
$(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i)
{          
val[i] = $(this).val();
$('#ct1').attr('href','http://shopping.sandbox.netsuite.com/app/site/backend/additemtocart.nl?c=4030365&n=1&buyid=multi&multi='+val[i]+','+qtyvalue);
});
}
</script>
```

But its adding only single check box and quantity field value to url not entire array.I want to add these values in format something like this

checkboxvalue,quantityvalue;checkboxvalue,quantityvalue;etc

I am new to java script and jquery so need help to figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over checked checkboxes and create new array that have checked value + comma separator + current qtyvalue

and then join them with `;` character:

```
var result = [];
$(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i){
 result.push($(this).val() + "," + $(this).parent().next().find('input').val());
});
var strreuslt = result.join(';'); // checkboxvalue,quantityvalue;checkboxvalue,quantityvalue;etc
$('#ct1').attr('href','http://shopping.sandbox.netsuite.com/app/site/backend/additemtocart.nl?c=4030365&n=1&buyid=multi&multi='+strreuslt);
```

Comment: Thanks for response but i am getting undefined quantity value.

Comment: @user2787474: can you share the problem fiddle

Comment: @user2787474: you have not used my code there, give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding the `href attr` in each loop that's why its appending the final value of `val array` in `href attr`

Try below one

```
<script>
function addURL(element)
{     
var qtyvalue = document.getElementById("qty").value;
var val = [];  
$(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i)
{          
val[i] = $(this).val();

});
$('#ct1').attr('href','http://shopping.sandbox.netsuite.com/app/site/backend/additemtocart.nl?c=4030365&n=1&buyid=multi&multi='+val.toString()+','+qtyvalue);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Generate a string with selected values and append after the loop. Like Below

```
 function addURL(element)
{     

var selectionString = '';  
$(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i)
{         

selectionString = selectionString + $(this).val()+','+$('.input').eq(i+1).text();

});
$('#ct1').attr('href','http://shopping.sandbox.netsuite.com/app/site/backend/additemtocart.nl?c=4030365&n=1&buyid=multi&multi=selectionString);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response but its adding only single check box and quantity field value not all selected values

Comment: Updated. Now it will select all checked check box values and Quantity.

Comment: Thanks but its not updating current selected check-box's associated input box value.its not updating input box value

Comment: So How the quantity textboxes are rendered ? share some sample html.

Comment: above solution will work only if all quantity textboxes are rendered with class "input".